# Online site sending me alert when pre-defined products appear on a site

Tags: open-source, email, email-client

My question is about to reveive an alert about a swiss online sales site between individuals (ricardo.ch), when a new announce contains some pre-defined key-tags word.

For example I would like to create Alert_1 with key word "*Lenovo*" and "*carbon*" for if a new announce named "*Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon core i5*" is created, I receive an email within 48 hours.

So, I don't need to check by myself every day if a new post which interests me is created.

Does such online opensource service exists ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a publicly accessible website that you want monitor for changes?

Comment: yes it is public

Comment: Is "opensource" necessary? Is it enough for it to be free or is it source code also necessary?

Comment: It is enough to be free, do you know any method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for website change detector, with ability to filter for keywords.

It can be done with tools like [huginn](https://github.com/huginn/huginn) that can be highly customized but with a bit complicated setup.

There are also multiple hosted services, some of them free (note that some handle only notifying that page changed, without ability to filter for only requested changes) - see list at https://github.com/edgi-govdata-archiving/awesome-website-change-monitoring#hosted-services